# ASP: Redirect to headless page and return

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I have an .aspx page that generates a report using the ReportViewer control. It is typically invoked from another page using Response.Redirect.

This page can be used in several ways. As long as the page generates a response, such as a MIME attachement, it works as expected. However, now I added the ability to generate the report and send it as an email attachement. In this scenario, the page is headless and does not produce a response on its own. Instead, I want to redirect back to the calling page and show a success message, as in:

Caller page -> Button Click -> Response.Redirect(Report page) -> process report -> Response.Redirect(Caller Page)

This works as intended in Chrome, but not in IE (8). The report is processed and the email is sent, but the 2nd redirect does not work and the browser times out. I considered using Server.Transfer for the redirect to the ReportViewer page. The timeout still occured in IE.

Can there not be 2 redirects in one request? What am I missing, and is there a better way to do this? 
This quoting from RFC1945 makes me think that the approach should be ok:

> A user agent should never automatically
>      redirect a request more than 5 times, since such redirections usually
>      indicate an infinite loop.

FYI, I want to keep all the report processing logic in the code-behind of the ReportViewer page if possible, because it interacts with the Response object in the normal scenario where the report is streamed back to he browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this was rather mundane. The method that renders the report and writes it to a file did a Response.ClearContent(). This was existing code that I brought over from a different application where this was required. Once I removed the call, the subsequent redirect began to work even in IE.

The final solution looks like this:

Caller page -> Button Click -> Validation -> Server.Transfer(Report page) -> process report -> Response.Redirect(Caller Page)

The caller page refreshes and shows a success message.

Answer (score 0):

Might I propose an alternate approach?
Caller page -> Button Click -> [POST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.method.aspx) -> process report -> GetRequestStream (i.e., "OK/Error") -> Do something

Comment: I am looking at this already, but there is a downside. The page is validating the email address before it redirects, and I would have to move that to the report page, which is is not where it belongs.